# How can I get the nth value from table headers with multiple search criteria

Tags: excel, search, indexing, filter, excel-formula

I am trying to return only table headers that start with SECTION and do not end with QUALITY. I can get the ones that start with SECTION but trying to apply an `AND(NOT())` function gives a `#CALC!` error.

Table headers are: SECTION_TITLE1, SECTION_TITLE1_QUALITY, SECTION_TITLE2, SECTION_TITLE2_QUALITY, etc.

I use _QUALITY for other formulas and for description.

Working but incomplete formula:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SECTION*",INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]")))),1)
```

Attempted formulas:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AND("SECTION*",NOT("*QUALITY")),INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]")))),1)
```

```
=INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),ISNUMBER(AND(SEARCH("SECTION*",INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]")),NOT(SEARCH("*QUALITY",INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]")))))),1)
```

```
=INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SECTION*",INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"))),NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*QUALITY",INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]")))))),1)
```

Comment: What would be your desired output?

Comment: Try `=LET(n,1,h,INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),INDEX(FILTER(h,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Section*",h))*ISERR(SEARCH("*Quality*",h))),n))`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use INDIRECT?

Comment: @VBasic2008 this worked, thank you! Do you want to add as an answer so I can select?

Comment: @P.b yes because I have a dropdown list of the different sheet names.

Comment: How many choices? Can't you do it with SWITCH()?

Comment: @user22954263 I'm out of time. To make the answer useful for other contributors, I need to clarify what is happening and why. It requires more than just the mere formula. I'll do it first thing tomorrow. Sorry. BTW, there is a 'slight' error in the formula: you need to use `"*Quality"`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I didn't know SEARCH accepts wildcards. Learned something new.

Comment: @P.b. I'm not familiar with SWITCH() but I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get n-th Excel Table Header With 2 Criteria

[image]

**Begin's with "Section" (A13)**

```
=LET(h,INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Section*",h)))
```

**Doesn't end with "Quality" (A15)**

```
=LET(h,INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),ISERR(SEARCH("*Quality",h)))
```

**Product of Both (converts to 1s and 0s) (A17)**

```
=LET(h,INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Section*",h))*ISERR(SEARCH("*Quality",h)))
```

**FILTER Applied (A19)**

```
=LET(h,INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),
FILTER(h,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Section*",h))*ISERR(SEARCH("*Quality",h))))
```

**INDEX Added (n=1) (A21)**

```
=LET(n,1,h,INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),
INDEX(FILTER(h,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Section*",h))
    *ISERR(SEARCH("*Quality",h))),n))
```

**INDEX Added (n=2) (A23)**

```
=LET(n,2,h,INDIRECT($D$10&"[#Headers]"),
INDEX(FILTER(h,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Section*",h))
    *ISERR(SEARCH("*Quality",h))),n))
```

**Lambda Formula (use in *Name Manager*) (A25)**

```
=LAMBDA(n,table,begins,ends_not,LET(
    h,INDIRECT(table&"[#Headers]"),
INDEX(FILTER(h,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(begins&"*",h))
    *ISERR(SEARCH("*"&"ends_not",h))),n)))
```

**Lambda Function "GetNthHeaderYBNE" (Usage) (n=1) (A27)**

```
=GetNthHeaderYBNE(1,$D$10,"Section","Quality")
```